# Default Result for Swift function

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, func

I'm currently using a simple method to test my textfield text like :

```
extension String {
  func test() -> Bool {
        return true
  }
}
```

Now if try my function on a concrete String, all is ok

`let result = myString.test()  //result is a Bool`

But if I execute it on an Optional String ( like `UITExtField.text` ), the type becomes `Optional<Bool>`

`let result = myOptionalString?.test()  //result is a Optional<Bool>`

Is there a way to provide a default value ( or implementation ) to avoid the test of the result when the caller is `Optional`.

*I Know I can use some operators like `??` or do an if-else statement, but it's lot of code for nothing*

Thanks!

Comment: Extend `UITextField` to add a `string` property that returns `text ?? ""`. (`UITextField` is the most common causer of this problem, and adding this extension makes whole classes of problems go away. As a rule, returning `String?` is a mistake because `nil` and `""` are almost always equivalent.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make extension for `Optional String`.

Example

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    func test() -> Bool {
        switch self {
        case .none: return false
        case .some(let string): return true
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it'll help you ;)

Comment: That's exactly what I as looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You could extend `Optional<String>` to return a default value if `nil`, or forward to `test()` if not.

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    func test() -> Bool {
        guard let value = self else { return false }
        return value.test()
    }
}
```